# excel with images is not loading using PHPExcel// files without images works fine. Any reason?

Tags: php

```
<?php
require ("Classes/PHPExcel.php");

require ("Classes/PHPExcel/IOFactory.php");


//include ("Classes/IOFactory.php");

$excel2 = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader("Excel2007");
echo "start";

$excel2 = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load('test.xls');


echo "loading working";
echo "<br/>";


$excel2->setActiveSheetIndex();



$excel2->getActiveSheet(0)

        ->setCellValue("G1", "Test tag no.")

        ->setCellValue("G2", "Test service")        

$file = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($excel2, "Excel5"); 


echo "edit working";

echo "<br/>";

$name = ('test.xls');


//$file->save("php://output");

//echo "Saving working";

//exit;


$file->save($name);

echo "Saving working";

?>
```

Comment: Is it giving any errors when you try loading?

Comment: when ever i referesh my page it shows me http 500 error\

Comment: i haven't check the errors

Comment: [Thu Oct 12 15:33:27.756567 2017] [:error] [pid 19381] [client ::1:37636] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class 'ZipArchive' not found in /var/www/html/Classes/PHPExcel/Reader/Excel2007.php:94\nStack trace:\n#0 /var/www/html/Classes/PHPExcel/IOFactory.php(280): PHPExcel_Reader_Excel2007->canRead('test.xls')\n#1 /var/www/html/Classes/PHPExcel/IOFactory.php(191): PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReaderForFile('test.xls')\n#2 /var/www/html/writetoexcel.php(10): PHPExcel_IOFactory::load('test.xls')\n#3 {main}\n  thrown in /var/www/html/Classes/PHPExcel/Reader/Excel2007.php on line 94

Comment: I'm amazed that it works with files that don't have images.... if it can't find ZipArchive, then it shouldn't be capable of loading any xlsx file

Comment: Why `$excel2 = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader("Excel2007");`? Do you need to create an Excel2007 Reader instance? You don't even use it

Comment: i am use Excel5 not Excel2007 and I am using xls file because 2007 xlsx dosn't work for me but this did

Comment: No, xlsx won't work because you don't have php_zip enabled; that's what the error is telling you

Comment: But it looks as though your `xls` file might actually be an `xlsx` file that has the wrong extension

Comment: but if the file is without images it works and as soon as i try to load a file that has pictures it just stop working !!!!!

Comment: if you're certain that it's an xls file, then instantiate the Excel5 Reader and use that directly, otherwise make sure that you have a build of PHP with php_zip enabled, because the generic loader is checking to see if `test.xls` is really an `xlsx` file... generally it wouldn't do that unless it had already tested to see if it was an `xls` file and failed to see it as such

Comment: And it's doing that whether the file contains images or not

Comment: well mr. baker i think you are correct. I saved the excel file in .xls on winodws and copy that in linux then i try to load the file and it works. But i also need to change the permissions also i totally forget about that part but yes i got it. still with .xlsx file its not working.